# How to retrieve and assign existing class to element without text content or class?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make a calendar that is made as a table and does not have text content or class assigned yet (besides `<thead>`).

This is what it initially looks like:

```js
      <div className="calendar">
        <header>

          <h2>{curMonth()}</h2>

          <button className="btn-prev fontawesome-angle-left" onClick={changePrevMonth}></button>
          <button className="btn-next fontawesome-angle-right" onClick={changeNextMonth}></button>

        </header>

        <table>

          <thead>

            <tr className="dow">

              <td>Su</td>
              <td>Mo</td>
              <td>Tu</td>
              <td>We</td>
              <td>Th</td>
              <td>Fr</td>
              <td>Sa</td>

            </tr>

          </thead>

          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
```

For `<tbody>`, I would like for it to use [calendar-dates npm package](https://dance2die.github.io/calendar-dates/#/) which returns the accurate day of the week for the last `a` number of days from the previous month, the `b` number of days for the current (focused) month, and the first `c` number of days from the following month.

My issue is when getting the `tbody tr` parts using `querySelectorAll()`, it returns null. Is there any way I can retrieve and assign class to the `<td>` portion that is by default empty and no class? Later, it will be able to change it if the text (date) exists and already has class.

Comment: Where are you calling `querySelectorAll`? The `tr` might not be added to the DOM when you call it. Make sure you wait until the DOM is ready before accessing it.

Comment: Is that HTML part of a react component? I've deleted my vanilla JavaScript answer because I noticed the react tag...

Comment: @traktor Yes, it is.